# pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: get_throttling_function_name: could not find match for multiple in pytube version 12.0.0

Tags: python, pytube

I'm trying to use pytube but every time I run the code this RegexError appears. I'm using pytube version 12.0.0 which is the latest. Does anyone have any solution?

Comment: related according to a non-answer posted as an answer: https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1678#issuecomment-1603948730

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because YouTube's updates. Try to change pytube's "cipher.py" file, function_patterns(should be around line 264) to:

```
r'a\.[a-zA-Z]\s*&&\s*\([a-z]\s*=\s*a\.get\("n"\)\)\s*&&\s*'
r'\([a-z]\s*=\s*([a-zA-Z0-9$]{2,3})(\[\d+\])?\([a-z]\)'
```

and also change line 288 to:

```
nfunc=re.escape(function_match.group(1))),
```

I believe pytube will release a official fix soon as well.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try this .

Comment: A similar problem is arising again. Till now, I didn't find any solution this time.